# Find an angle between a triangle and a plane

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solid-geometry

> The hypotenuse $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ lies in plane $Q$. Sides $AC$ and $BC $, respectively, create angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ towards the plane Q (meaning they are tilted towards the plane $Q$ with such angles). Find the angle between plane $Q$ and the plane of the triangle, given $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{1}{3} $ and $\sin(\beta)=\frac{\sqrt5}{6}$.

I'm really struggling with these kinds of problems and I can't seem to find any material in English that covers this topic. Only videos I found about planes use  normal vectors and equation of the plane, which is not necessary for this.

The picture wasn't given but Here's my interpretation:

[image]

let $CK$ be the perpendicular line from point $C$ to plane $Q$. $CD$ is the height of triangle $ABC$. What I'm struggling to understand is what will the dihedral angle be in this case? Well, I know that the angle between two planes is the angle between two perpendicular lines of such planes. One of which must be $CD$, but what will the other line be?  Is it $KD$? How can I know for sure that $KD$ is a perpendicular line?

Anyway, I don't think I'm understanding the problem clearly. If someone can provide a graphical solution, i'll be very thankful.

Comment: Yes, that's what they're asking. However, i'm not supposed to use the formula for planes, or normal vectors for that matter.

Comment: $KD\perp AB$ by the [Theorem of Three Perpendiculars](https://www.math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html).

Comment: @Aretino I think, methodical it's not so good theorem. It helps maybe for solving easy problems.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm afraid I don't understand what you wrote. I was just answering "How can I know for sure that  is a perpendicular line?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $AB\perp CD$ and $AB\perp CK$, which says $AB\perp(CDK)$ and from here $AB\perp DK$.

Let $CK=h$ and $\measuredangle CDK=\phi$.

Thus, $$\sin\phi=\frac{h}{DC}=\frac{h}{\frac{AC\cdot BC}{\sqrt{AC^2+BC^2}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin\beta}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin^2\alpha}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\beta}}}}=\sqrt{\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $\phi=30^{\circ}.$

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct. I'm having trouble understanding the 3rd step, could you explain the simplification? I'm aware that $AC \sin(\alpha) = h$ and $BC\sin(\beta) = h $

Comment: So $AC\cdot BC $ would be $= \frac{h^2}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)}$ right?

Comment: Oh, you took the $h^2$ from the square root and divided numerator and denominator by h, thus we're left with no $h$. I understood now.

Comment: @Ebrin I saw you comment only now. Is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I was able to understand your solution clearly and I managed to solve the problem from there. However, my main issue is I lack the intuition to understand the first part: "$AB\perp(CD)$ and $AB\perp(CK)$, which says $AB\perp(CDK)$". Does $CDK$ refer to the triangle? That property might be rather trivial, but if you could provide a bit more intuition for why that's the case, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Ebrin Just if we want to prove that $a\perp b$ we need one of these lines to put in the plane and to prove that the second line is a perpendicular to the plane. We need to prove that $DK\perp AB$. We see that $DK\subset(DKC)$ and it's enough to prove that $AB\perp(DKC),$ which we made.